# mysql multi-source replication to single slave from Debian repo's?

Tags: mysql, replication, backup, debian, mysql-5.7

I've been experimenting with mysql 5.7's feature to backup multiple sources to a single slave, but have legacy db's on source servers where I'm not sure if upgrading to 5.7 will break things, and also I want to use standard packages in Debian repositories to more standardized support. Does anyone have experience doing something like this, and/or is there a better way to approach it?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to upgrade the master servers until you want to.

Officially, replication *requires* that the slave server be the same version as the master *or newer*.  That might seem counterintuitive, but derives from the fact that the replication protocol is always forward-extensible, but not always backward-compatible.  New capabilities can be added to the replication format, and when this happens, it only adds to what the master *might* write, but it adds to what the slave *must* be able to interpret.

As a rule, newer slaves know all the tricks an older master can do.  In contrast, newer masters can blow the mind of an older slave, by doing things the older slave won't recognize.

Because of the way replication is designed, the slave can actually learn the version of a master, but the master has essentially no way to learn the same information about a slave... nor is this needed, because the master only has one binlog, and all connected slaves receive exactly the same event stream.

Officially, replication is supported with a gap of one major release... the slave running 5.5 with a master running 5.1 (GA skipped from 5.1 to 5.5, so that's "one.") or the slave running 5.6 and master running 5.5, etc.

Unofficially, from 5.1 onward, you can generally make it work with any gap in the releases, as long as the slave is always newer, and you don't enable slave features the master doesn't implement, where the feature requires both servers to have the same configuration, such as binlog checksums or GTIDs. (...and you understand that Oracle won't be interested in any bug reports about a larger gap not working...)

Connecting a 5.7 slave to any number of pre-5.7 should be workable... but an important point here, relevant to your situation is that in the master/slave relationship, the slave is really in control of the entire interaction.  It initiates the connection to the master, sets any options on the connection, and asks the master to start sending the replication stream.  The master then dutifully sends replication events until the slave disappears, at which time the master closes the abandoned connection and forgets all about the slave.

Try it. The worst thing that should be possible is that you may have to change some defaults on the slave to get it to negotiate successfully with the older masters, but the older masters should not need any changes or be negatively impacted in any way by a connection from newer slave.

---

It's a matter of opinion, but I never, ever let the package manager mess with my MySQL servers. The package manager can be a bit of a black box, and if anybody is going to screw up my servers, it's going to be me.  If an upgrade ever fails, it's going to be me who broke it. If you use the "Linux Generic" tarballs from Oracle, it's pretty straightforward.

If you symlink `/usr/local/mysql` to point to the tarball's extraction directory (which is named for the version and architecture) and then symlink `data` inside the extraction directory to point to your "datadir," then upgrading MySQL to a new version is as simple as extracting the new tarball, stopping the server daemon, changing 2 symlinks, restarting the daemon, and running `mysql_upgrade`. If the new version won't start for any reason, well, hey, the old version is still right there.  Move the symlinks back, and punt.

The only dependency you have to take care of manually is installing `libaio1`, which is in the standard distro repositories, just not installed by default.

Comment: I'm running 5.7 as my slave, and older versions as sources/masters, so will try what you suggest. It seemed to me like the slave would need to know about multiple source/masters and support the CHANNEL feature, but masters shouldn't really care what version the slave was, but the doc I read seemed to say I had to use FOR CHANNEL as part of a command on the master, meaning the master needed to support the CHANNEL feature.

Comment: `CHANGE MASTER ... FOR CHANNEL` and `START SLAVE ... FOR CHANNEL` would both be statements executed at the slave.  The channels seem to be only arbitrary text labels for replication configuration, and only used on and meaningful at the slave, but if you encounter something that contradicts that, feel free to ask.

Comment: My slave gives me syntax errors when I run: `change master to master_host="1.2.3.4", master_port=3306, master_user="masterusers",master_password="whatever" for channel="blah";` so does that mean the slave doesn't support channels, or what should I be using here?

Comment: It's helpful if you post the exact error message.  `SELECT @@VERSION;` to confirm that the version running on the server is what you expect it to be.

Comment: `5.7.5-m15-log` version, error: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'for channel="blah"' at line 1`